# SFTP connection unsupported key format

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to a remote server using a SFTP connection with visual studio code. I'm using the [sftp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp)
extension. The error I'm getting says that my private key is in the wrong format. [image]

The configuration file looks like this. 
[image]

My private key is in an openSSH format. How do I get it to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the Mac private key format. Generating a key in PEM format gets rid of the error. 
https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/391